# How to get font awesome icon in code?

Tags: html, fonts

I'm trying to get fontawesome icon in this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test revealUpFull">
        <img src="games/racegame/foto/fotozonder.PNG" width="260" height="195" />
        <span class="title"><a href="game1.html">Racegame<br /><br /> with some more info</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I wanna do is to place an icon `fa-home active` instead of text "with some more info" . How can I get it in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `<i class="fa fa-home icon active"></i>` where you want the icon to appear. Make sure you included fontawesome in your head.

Two icons with text:

```
<i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
<br/>
<i class="fa fa-car"></i> Racing game
<br/>
```

Comment: but one more problem like i want to add text behind that how do i do that? and on the next line i need another icon how do i fix that to?

Comment: I modified my code for two icons beneath each other. Depending on your CSS this might not work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Have you inserted the following code after your `<head>`?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

See the official page for more info:
http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

As @IkoTikashi said, you need to warp it with `<i class="fa fa-home icon active"></i>`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2p9dzzk9/4/

Comment: yes i did i only need the icon to appear i have a part right now with this code
<div class="container">
            <div class="test revealUpFull">
              <img src="games/racegame/foto/fotozonder.PNG" width="260" height="195" />
              <span class="title"><a href="game1.html">Racegame<br /><br /><i class="icon fa-clock-o"></i> 8 Weken<br><i class="icon fa-clock-o"></i></a></span>
            </div>
           </div>